# A result for positive definite matrices..

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite

Let $A=(a_{i,j})_{1\leq i,j\leq n }$ be a $n\times n$ positive definite matrix. Then show that $$\det A \leq a_{11}a_{22}\cdots a_{nn}$$

I have done this for $2 \times2 $ matrix.

Comment: Do you include "symmetric" in your definition of "positive-definite"? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: yes by positive definite I mean symmetric also @ Michel Hardy

Comment: It is the famous [Hadamard's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard%27s_inequality#Alternate_forms_and_corollaries) for positive-definite matrices.